# Icedtea-web error while accessing KVM Console through CIMC

Tags: linux, fedora, arch-linux, java, jdk

I want to access the KVM Console through CIMC but icedtea-web keep showing the below error.

Currently I'm using

- Distribution: Fedora 26
- icedtea-web.x86_64 1.7-6.fc26
- openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)

The error:

```
net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Initialization Error: Could not initialize application. The application has not been initialized, for more information execute javaws from the command line.
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:817)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.launchApplication(Launcher.java:529)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher$TgThread.run(Launcher.java:940)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.jnlp.LaunchException: Fatal: Initialization Error: Unknown Main-Class. Could not determine the main class for this application.
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.initializeResources(JNLPClassLoader.java:704)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.<init>(JNLPClassLoader.java:285)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.createInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:357)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:429)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.runtime.JNLPClassLoader.getInstance(JNLPClassLoader.java:403)
    at net.sourceforge.jnlp.Launcher.createApplication(Launcher.java:809)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: you can use HTML based KVM